Tantalum capacitor for op amps
Normally for opamps supply voltages, it is suggested that there should be (100 nF + 2-10 uF) on the positive and negative supply pins. The second capacitor which is in range of uF should tantalum? Or X7R is fine?


Suggestion from Analogue Device for component selection:

My second question would be, should we always put another 100 nF, in between positive and negative supply pins? As in is in the schematic (C4).

As an aside,it is probably worth mentioning not to use hi-k dielectric like X7R caps in the signal path as they are piezo-electric and can act as microphones.

@Kartman Thank you for the useful comment, I want to use them just for my supply pins, it that ok?

Practically speaking, I have used the following guidelines for years, with designs comprising many (single/dual/quad) opamps ber board, and never had problems:

one largish (say 220u/470u) cap per rail where power enters the board (or near the regulator output if there are on board regulators)
one 10uF electrolytic or ceramic per rail every 5cm of trace or so
one ceramic 0.1uF per rail for each IC, as close as feasible to the IC supply pins.

I have not used tanatalums*, or seen them in regular use for several decades. I do have the unusual bragging rights to the fact that when I serviced early digital audio gear around 40 years ago, I replaced every single tantalum decoupling cap in a Lexicon 224, belonging to a well-known female pop singer, whose farmhouse studio had been suffered a lightning strike. (Around half the tants had failed short circuit.) I replaced with electrolytics and everything worked fine. Later models of that unit used electrolytics in place of tants anyway.
( * not quite true, I did develop a sample-and-hold later that needed very long storage times, for that I used a tantalum, for its combination of high capacitance and low leakage. That was over 20 years ago though.)

There have been attempts to phase out tantalum capacitors, since they are fragile and made from conflict minerals (main source of Coltan is the DRC).

@ danmcb can I used this cap for the 470 UF? https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/chemi-con/HHXJ160ARA471MHA0G/17728580

@Andromeda the choice of 10u and larger caps is in general not critical - as long as they have enough working voltage. Try it, build the prototype, test it. I am not going to review your component selections. :-)

What's generally most important is having a supply impedance that is low and stable.  Not as low as possible, but low enough.
Unfortunately, datasheets never stipulate how low that is, but given they usually suggest capacitors of some ohms to fractional ohms ESR, we can take this as a baseline figure.
And we can take at least the op-amp GBW as the required frequency range.  It might extend above this by a decade or more, depending on internal structure, hard to say; but we probably need at least this.
Any equivalent will suffice.  Electrolytics are generally adequate, but mind that they are temperature-dependent, in particular rising at low temperature.
Tantalum have the distinction of modest and stable ESR, which made them attractive back in the day, especially for compensation purposes where a narrow range of ESR might be required, such as early LDOs.  They're frowned upon these days, as tantalum is a conflict mineral, and equivalent value can be obtained from ceramic with a series resistor added (at modest expense to ESL, as both chip body lengths add together).
Polymer capacitors are also available in a wide range of ESR, mostly on the low side, but selected values can be higher.
Very low ESR values, in relation to capacitance and circuit inductance (component plus trace/strays), are undesirable as resonances are encouraged: the valley impedance might be as low as the ESR is, but the peak impedance is Q times higher, where \$Q = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}}{ESR}\$ for suitable combinations of L, C and ESR.  As L goes up or ESR down, the peaks get taller.  As C goes up, the peaks get lower -- you can swamp it out by using more -- but beware larger C's usually have lower ESR too.
Note that stray inductance is simply trace length, give or take a geometry factor depending on trace width and height above substrate.   0.5nH/mm is a typical figure.  From this, we can determine the inductance from layout, assuming a ground plane design of course.

@ Tim Williams thank you very much for the nice response,  in case I can use the tantalum version for uF range, then I understand, that is a good option to be used right?

It's probably fine. Mind, I can't be sure it's a "good" option without knowing the whole design.

I edited this post and added a lot of schematic and information about the project. Would you please let me know your idea based on this?

Same conclusion. When I say "whole", I mean from project specifications to everything on the circuit board, and everything it connects to; likely some of those things aren't a factor in the conclusion, but knowing which ones to omit is non-trivial so including everything would be best. Also, at that point, you should start a new question; but given the potential volume of data required, you might not receive an answer (or a comprehensive enough one), and engaging a contractor would be most promising. Cheers!
